# this.balance VS address(this).balance

Tags: solidity, contract-development, remix

What is the difference between  `this.balance` VS `address(this).balance` in solidity contracts?

Answer (score 17):

`this` represents a "contract instance" object for the current contract. The `balance` function is part of the "address" object. You used to be able to do `this.balance` because solidity would allow implicit access to the address functions through the contract instance object.

However, as of Solidity 0.4.22, the [recommended practice](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/v0.4.22/types.html#members-of-addresses) is to use `address(this).balance` which explicitly converts `this` (the current contract instance) to an `address` object.

[In Solidity 0.5.0, `this.balance` will be explicitly forbidden](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/units-and-global-variables.html#address-related), and you will be required to explicitly convert to the address object before you can access it's functions.

You may find code using the older syntax due to historical practices, but you should use the modern syntax for any new contracts that you write.

Answer (score 1):

I have to use this, but im on the Energi chain

Solidity 0.7.5

> return (payable(address(this))).balance;

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/46023)

Comment: Yes, thats the problem, I would have liked to comment, but i seem to be stuck at 11  Anyway, maybe it helps someone with the same problem, because i needed 1 hour googling and stumbled across this question.

Comment: Answer to newer questions to get more reputation. Eventually a moderator will move your answer to the comments section.

Comment: I was stuck for like 2 weeks, apparently (for me at least), it can only work if it is casted to payable. THANKS!